# Only check formfields with certain class instead of every field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

The code below checks if every form field is filled with and then automatically submits it. How can I make sure that instead of checking every field, it only checks the fields with class "must_be_filled"?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search >:input").keyup(function() {
    var $emptyFields = $('#search :input').filter(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value) === "";
     });
    if (!$emptyFields.length) {
        document.getElementById('submit_button').click();
            }
     });
});
```

Comment: Selecting by class is one of the most fundamental and simple uses of jQuery, any amount of research should have helped you find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
$('#search :input')
```

with

```
$('#search :input.must_be_filled')
```